# Says 'AnimalShelter' object has no attritbute 'create' but everything is there?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, crud

I am trying to test my AnimalShelter.py code in Jupyter Notebook but I keep getting the error that the 'create' attribute is not there. Did I miss something? I have it defined in the code but no matter what I change it still says it is not there.

AnimalShelter.py code:

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        #Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to access the MongoDB databases and collections.
        self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:45344' % (username, password))
        #where xxxx is your unique port number
        self.database = self.client['AAC']
    
#Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        if data is not None:
            insert = self.database.animals.insert(data) #data should be dictionary
        
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")
            
#Create method to implement the R in CRUD.
    def read(self, searchData):
        if searchData:
            data = self.database.animals.find(searchData, {"_id": False})
        
        else:
            data = self.database.animals.find({}, {"_id": False})
        return data

#Create method to implement U in CRUD.
    def update(self, searchData, updateData):
        if searchData is not None:
            result = self.database.animals.update_many(searchData, {"$set": updateData})
        else:
            return "{}"
        return result.raw_result

#Create method to implement D in CRUD.
    def delete(self, deleteData):
        if deleteData is not None:
            result = self.database.animals.delete_many(deleteData)
        
        else:
            return "{}"
        return result.raw_result
```

The test code I am trying to use to see that CRUD is functioning properly:

```
from AnimalShelter import AnimalShelter

data = {}
query = {}

test_class = AnimalShelter()

#test each function in the AnimalShelter class
response = test_class.create(data)
assert response

response = test_class.read(data)
assert response

response = test_class.update(data)
assert response

response = test_class.delete(data)
assert response
```

I am at a loss. I am new to Jupyter Notebook with the whole testing thing and I figured this was the simplest way to test the attributes before making a different test for specific data from the python code but either way I still get that the create attribute doesn't exist!

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a slightly altered version of your code for easy testing and got the error that no `username` and `password` were being passed to the `AnimalShelter` constructor.

```py
class AnimalShelter(object):
    """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print("constructor")
    
#Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.
    def create(self, data):
        print("create")
            
#Create method to implement the R in CRUD.
    def read(self, searchData):
        print("read")

#Create method to implement U in CRUD.
    def update(self, searchData, updateData):
        print("update")

#Create method to implement D in CRUD.
    def delete(self, deleteData):
        print("delete")

test_class = AnimalShelter("user", "pass")
data = {}

test_class.create(data)
test_class.read(data)
test_class.update(data, {})
test_class.delete(data)
```

Could your error be because you didn't pass these variables when constructing the `test_class` object? Upon passing `"user"` and `"pass"`, I got the expected output:

```
constructor
create
read
update
delete
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that by not putting the username and password behind test_class = AnimalShelter() that it was giving me an error! I will try to apply this to my other test(s) and see if that fixes my problem!